# find the minimum value

Tags: real-analysis

when $$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n (x-ai)^2$$ where a1,a2.....$a_n$
       find the value of the x where f is minimum.

is this question asking about local minimum? and answer is just x = ai ??

Comment: Those are (presumably) different $a_i$'s.  What do you mean by $x = a_i$?

Comment: That would be a parabola, so local minimum would be the same as the global minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: using calculus, show
$$f'(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n 2(x-a_i) \implies f'(x)=0 \text{ when } x = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}n $$

and $f''(x) = 2n > 0$.

Comment: why there is 1/n

Comment: If you expand the summation, will be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

without calculus, you can do it as follow:

$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n (x-ai)^2=\sum_{i=1}^n(x^2-2xa_i+a_i^2)=\sum_{i=1}^nx^2-2\sum_{i=1}^nxa_i+\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2=nx^2-2(\sum_{i=1}^na_i)x+\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2=n\left(x-\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^na_i}{n}\right)^2+\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2-\dfrac{(\sum_{i=1}^na_i)^2}{n}$